# Error 70' when working with combobox Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

im really new to this, im trying to make a VBA program that finds a row depending on the criteria you put in, but gives error '70', permission denied

There's an old thread that lead me to this problem, here:
[Old thread with the begining of my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041471/change-rowsource-to-different-storage-maybe-list?noredirect=1#comment125652574_71041471)

This problem started with an error when filling the combobox, plz if anyone know hoe to solve this please help, im very lost with this matter

Thanks in advance

This is the full code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox10_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = Null Then
TextBox1.Enabled = False
Else
TextBox1.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TabStrip1_Change()
Call UpdateRevenue
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

NumeroDatos = Hoja1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
Me.Lista = Clear
Me.Lista.RowSource = "'Hoja1'!TablaPrincipal"

For fila = 4 To NumeroDatos



'-----------------------------
'----variables de valores-----
'-----------------------------
link = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
descrip = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
informe = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
fecha = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
comuna = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
sector = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
calle = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
tipo = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
superficie = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
valorUF = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
'-----------------------------
'----variables de valores-----
'-----------------------------


'-----------------------------
'----Si el link coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then
   If UCase(link) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si la descripción coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1 Then
   If UCase(descrip) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si el informe coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2 Then
   If UCase(informe) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si la fecha coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 3 Then
   If UCase(fecha) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si la comuna coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 4 Then
   If UCase(comuna) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si el sector coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 5 Then
   If UCase(sector) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si la calle coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 6 Then
   If UCase(calle) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si el tipo coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 7 Then
   If UCase(tipo) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si la superficie coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 8 Then
   If UCase(superficie) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
'-----------------------------
'----Si el valorUF coincide-----
'-----------------------------
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 9 Then
   If UCase(valorUF) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
   Me.Lista.AddItem
   Me.Lista.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 3).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 4).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 5).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 6).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 7).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 8).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 8) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 9).Value
   Me.Lista.List(y, 9) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 10).Value
   y = y + 1
   End If
 End If
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 

Next

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Me.Lista.RowSource = "TablaPrincipal"
Me.Lista.ColumnCount = 10
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


'Get the List Object
    Dim myList As ListObject
    Set myList = Hoja1.ListObjects("TablaPrincipal") 'CHANGE "List1" TO MATCH YOUR TABLE'S NAME
    
    'Get the Headers
    Dim ListHeaders As Range
    Set ListHeaders = myList.HeaderRowRange
    
    'Create an empty Array
    Dim Headers() As String
    ReDim Headers(ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1)
    
    'Fill the Array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1
        Headers(i) = ListHeaders.Cells(i + 1)
    Next
    
    'Put the Array into the ComboBox
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Headers

   
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought the issue was clearly identified in the previous question?  You have set the rowsource here: `Me.Lista.RowSource = "'Hoja1'!TablaPrincipal"` so you cannot later call `Me.Lista.AddItem`   BTW there is far too much code here to expect anyone to make sense of it - you would get better results if you restrict what you post to only the *minimum required to show the problem*

Comment: yes, im clear that i can't use AddItem, what can i use instead please?

Comment: If you want to add content to a listbox where you've used Rowsource then you would need to add the content to the source range and adjust the RowSource property to include the new content.

Comment: Is it possible you could help me with some example code? im very lost here, i know only few things about VBA, i don't know how to apply what you just told me, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want i think:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    TextBox1.Enabled = ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1
End Sub

'add a listobject datarow range to a listbox
Private Sub RowToList(rw As Range, lst As MSForms.ListBox)
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    lst.AddItem
    r = UBound(lst.List, 1)
    For i = 1 To rw.Cells.Count
        lst.List(r, i - 1) = rw.Cells(i)
    Next i
End Sub

'this is the one place to edit the source listobject
Private Function SourceList() As ListObject
    Set SourceList = Hoja1.ListObjects("TablaPrincipal")
End Function

'clear a listbox
Private Sub ClearList(lst As MSForms.ListBox)
    If Len(lst.RowSource) > 0 Then
        lst.RowSource = ""
    Else
        lst.Clear
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim rw As Range, v, lo As ListObject, i As Long
    Dim colNum As Long
    
    Set lo = SourceList
    v = Me.TextBox1.Value
    ClearList Me.Lista
    
    If Len(v) > 0 Then 'any search term?
        colNum = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1 'which column are we searching on?
        v = "*" & lcase(v) & "*" 'convert to lower case for comparisons
        For Each rw In lo.DataBodyRange.Rows
            'convert list value to lower case for case-insensitive comparison
            If LCase(rw.Cells(colNum).Value) Like v Then 'check the relevant column
                RowToList rw, Me.Lista
            End If
        Next rw
    Else
        Me.Lista.RowSource = lo 'no search term: reload the whole table
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.Lista.RowSource = SourceList
    Me.Lista.ColumnCount = SourceList.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count 'dynamic
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim myList As ListObject, ListHeaders As Range
    Dim Headers() As String, i As Long
    Set myList = SourceList
    Set ListHeaders = myList.HeaderRowRange
    ReDim Headers(ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To ListHeaders.Cells.Count - 1
        Headers(i) = ListHeaders.Cells(i + 1)
    Next
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Headers
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my god, it looks like it works! Is it possible you can help me so the search doesnt care about caps? so M and m is the same?? Thank you for your coding and time!
Also, can you explain me how you get the search filters? I'm so curious on how you got them!

Comment: See edits for case-insensitive comparison: basically convert both terms to lower case before using `Like`.   I'm not sure what you mean by "search  filters"?  All the code does is loop over the rows of the source listobject, select the appropriate column (based on the combobox selection) and then compare the values in that column of the listobject data to the textbox value.

Comment: hey, ok i'll try to make it, also, when i search for the date, it change the value formats in the search, do you know why?
https://i.gyazo.com/f7465fe107d89359b21e71001ffa1494.mp4

Comment: How dates display in the listbox will depend on your local setttings - if you want to show some specific format then add the date to the listbox after passing it through `Format()` to get the string representation you want.  I notice in your screenshot you have both m/d/yy and d/m/yy dates in the same column, which is not a good idea.